# how to change context path of tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, cpanel

In netbeans I can right click on project name, select properties > run > and change the context path, 
how can I change the context path of the tomcat on my server which is accessible using cPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add root.xml file in  `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` and add this as :

```
 <Context 
   docBase="/opt/mywebapps/<yourApp>" 
   path="" 
   reloadable="true" 
  />
```

For more detail you can use the Apache context configuration link : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: By default, CATALINA_HOME is /usr/share/tomcat6, and CATALINA_BASE is /var/lib/tomcat6.

Comment: these both can be set in /etc/default/tomcat6.

Comment: I do not how to access these, should I access them using ssh ?

Comment: In ubuntu tomcat v6, if installed at /usr/lib/tomcat6/...
both variables are stored in /etc/init.d/tomcat6

Comment: chech this link contain unix/linux system access of this: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200505.mbox/%3C427A6C44.8030707@objektpark.de%3E