# How to change the context path of a Spring MVC application deployed in TOMCAT 6.0

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-mvc, tomcat6

I have a application by the name (say ) SR.DEV.1.001.war . The builds will change as might have thought already to SR.DEV.1.001 ..004 and so  on . However, the jsp's inside have links like DS/admin or DS/user .

I have checked online for a few resources so as to help me , like [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/87915/Tomcat/tomcat-define-context-root-diff) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454841/how-to-change-context-path-of-tomcat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

After trying them out, Im still having the same issue .
I tried in context.xml in META-INF

```
  01)  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <Context  docBase="/SR.DEV.1.001.war"  path=""  reloadable="true" />

  02) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <Context  docBase="/SR.DEV.1.001.war"  path="/"  reloadable="true" />

  03) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <Context  docBase="/"  path="/DS"  reloadable="true" />

  04) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <Context  docBase=""  path="/DS"  reloadable="true" />
```

Please help me fix the issue , as without which , its difficult for me to manage the versions of the war , without affecting the context .

If it helps, I also have a redirect.jsp which is loaded as welcome file in web.xml.

```
         redirect.jsp : 

        <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
        <%response.sendRedirect("/DS/pdui/show.do"); %>
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

When adding a context.xml to the META-INF directory of the web application you should only need to specify the path, the other fields are deducted from where the application is deployed. The docBase is [only needed](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) if you specify the path inside the hosts or server.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/DS"  reloadable="true" />
```

So basically the above should be enough, make sure that you don't have any leftovers from your previous attempts as that might influence how this works. (Although I believe this one should take precedence over the others).

Comment: hi Deinum , First of all thanks for the update . I did how you suggested , however , somehow it did not work . I deleted the log files , cleaned the work folder , cleaned the \conf\Catalina\localhost\ folder any left overs ...

After deployment i see SR.DEV.1.001.xml file in \conf\Catalina\localhost directory .

However, when I tried going to the http://localhost:8080/DS it dint work . Any suggesstions , or anything else I need to worry about ?

Comment: Can you post he context of the context.xml file. Also make sure that you don't have leftovers in the server.xml file of tomcat.

Comment: context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Context path="/DS" reloadable="true"/>

Comment: Server.xml in conf folder : There is no change than the default one that comes along with TOMCAT.

Comment: After deployment there should be a file with the name of the `<war>.xml` which is what appears to be happening... Now what isn't working? Also which change are you hinting at? Normally there is no change to the server.xml...

Comment: The problem I'm facing is : I should be able to access http://localhost:8080/DS/admin 
or http://localhost:8080/DS/user. 

But, if Im changing the build number, I can access the project by 
: http://localhost:8080/SR.DEV.1.001/admin  ....      http://localhost:8080/SR.DEV.2.001/admin and so on.

Comment: I have not seen any replies on this yet . Im still facing the issue and struggling to move ahead . I would be thankful , if I could use some help.